# Unable to pass data between two controllers

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Simply trying to pass data between two controllers, Im able to jump to the next view controller screen but my number isn't updating.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var numOnScreen: UILabel!
  //numOnScreen gets updated else where in my code. 

//MY BUTTON THAT SWITCHES MY VIEW 
    @IBAction func storyBoardAdder(_ sender: Any) {
        

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Send_VC")
        as! Send_ViewController
        vc.sendamm = numOnScreen.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

sendamm should be updating on my next screen but it's not.

```
//MY RECEIVING VIEW CONTROLLER CODE

@IBOutlet weak var myCash: UILabel!
    var sendamm: String = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCash.text = "$\(sendamm)"
        
}
```

Ive made sure that numOnScreen isn't getting cleared before reaching my function I did
vc.sendamm = "100"
And im still unable to see anything in my other view controller, I've made sure my vc identifiers are correct and made sure my IBOutlets are all linked properly.

Comment: Change `var sendamm: String = ""` to `var sendamm: String = "abc"`, and see if "abc" shows up on screen in your `myCash` label. Then, add `print("sendamm: \(sendamm)")` in `viewDidLoad()` and see what gets printed there.

Comment: Make sure that you haven't created a segue directly from your button to the second view controller. You should only have a `touchUpInside` handler for your button

Comment: Changing sendamm to "abc" updated the label and printed abc

Comment: @Joshua - `// comment out` all code in your `@IBAction func storyBoardAdder` func. Run the app, and see what happens when you tap the button. ***IF*** you get pushed to `Send_ViewController`, then you have a `Segue` that is pushing to `Send_ViewController`. And, if that is the case, then you probably do **NOT** have the button connected to your `@IBAction` -- if you have both, you would be seeing `Send_ViewController` pushed ***twice*** - once with "abc and once with the value from `numOnScreen.text`

Answer (score 1):

You're using a string property in the destination rather than trying to set the label.text directly, which is good.

Something may be loading your destination VC's view hierarchy before you set your variable, so viewDidLoad fires before you set the `sendamm` property.

Try moving your code `myCash.text = "$\(sendamm)"` to `viewWillAppear(animated:)` instead of `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried
`
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        myCash.text = "$ \(sendamm)"
    }
`
    But was unable to receive any thing in my other view

Comment: The code you posted in your comment isn't quite right. (it should be `myCash.text = "$\(sendamm)"`. You're missing a backslash.) I'd start out by printing the value of your `sendamm` property to the console in viewWillAppear. If it appears correctly, then figure out how to get the value into your label.